# SQL Query to transform data for Reports

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at transforming the below data into which it could be projected in the reports, but in Vain. Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Student - Table
----------------
StudentID | CertID
------------------
1         | 10
2         | 20

Certification Table
-------------------
CertId | CertName
-------------------
10       Certification1
20       Certification2
30       Certification3    

Capablity Table
---------------
CapId | Capablity
-------------------
1       Capability1
2       Capability2
3       Capability3
4       Capability4
5       Capability5
6       Capability6

StudentCertification
--------------------
StudentID | CertId | CapId | TotalTasks | CompletedTasks
--------------------------------------------------------------
1           10           1           50           25
1           20           2           20            5
2           10           4           30           12
```

I am looking for a final data which looks like this

```
StudentId | CertId | CapId| TasksCompleted
---------------------------------
1           10           1         50%
1           10           2         NA
1           10           3         NA
1           10           4         NA
1           10           5         NA
1           10           6         NA
1           20           1         NA
1           20           2         25%
1           20           3         NA
1           20           4         NA
1           20           5         NA
1           20           6         NA
2           10           1         NA
2           10           2         NA
2           10           3         NA
2           10           4         40%
2           10           5         NA
2           10           6         NA
```

I have updated the result to reflect data from Student-Certification table as well.

Comment: What part of the query are you struggling with?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you're unsure how to get started look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp; looking at the definitions of the different joins.

Comment: I am basically struggling in getting data for a combination of Student-Certification-capability even if there is no mapping for "Student-Certification-capability" in "StudentCertification" table. Basically, a Student will not have all the capabilities under a certification they are assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT SC1.StudentID ,SC1.CertId,C.CapId,
CAST((100*SC2.CompletedTasks)/SC2.TotalTasks AS VARCHAR(20)) + '%' AS TasksCompleted  
FROM StudentCertification SC1
CROSS JOIN capability  C
LEFT JOIN  StudentCertification SC2 ON SC1.StudentID=SC2.StudentID
AND SC1.CertId=SC2.CertId AND C.CapId=SC2.CapId
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fde699/1) to view result

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example. Didn't really understand the functionality of capability table, but with cross join you'll get all the combinations for each student.

```
select
  s.StudentId,
  c.CertId,
  cb.CapId,
  100.0 * sc.CompletedTasks / sc.TotalTasks as TasksCompleted
from
  student s
  left outer join certification c on c.CertId = s.CertId
  cross join capability cb
  left outer join StudentCertification sc on 
      s.StudentId = sc.StudentId and c.CertId = sc.CertId and cb.CapId = sc.CapId
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1145e/5

Comment: Apologies. I have updated how the result set should be.     For every student, for all the certifications from "Student - Certification" table, I require rows for every capability. If there are rows for a particular capability in "StudentCertification", then "PercentageTask Completed" will have data, else NULL.

Comment: You don't have a row for student 1 for cert 20, maybe something wrong with your data?

Comment: And 2 has 20, but in the other table it has 10, so another problem with your data

Comment: Yes. The data in the Student table is to identify what is a student's Primary certification. All their secondary certifications is mapped in "Student Certification" table

Comment: And you didn't think that's something you should mention? Well, you should be able to make a suitable query from this.

Comment: apologies. i appreciate your time. would be grateful if you could help me out in this query.

Comment: Start with studentcertification and cross / outer join other tables to that

Comment: I tried that. Like "Select *,100.0 * s.CompletedTasks / s.TotalTasks from StudentCertification s
Cross Join Capability cb
Where StudentID = 1 and CertId = 10" . THis gives me 12 rows which is right as "StudentCertification" table has 2 entries for StudentID = 1